# Convert string to Macros in C++

Tags: c++, string, macros

I want to print the value of my macros through a string
Given Code

```
#include<iostream>
#define abc 7

using namespace std;

int main()
{
 string str = "abc";
 cout<<str<<endl;
}
```

Output should be 7 if i do cout str

Comment: since macros are just replaced with their values, how about `cout<<abc<<endl;`

Comment: The problem is - i will read the str value from a file and there will be multiple macros in that file

Comment: Bad question (very unclear), lacking some [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You could consider some [X macro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Macro)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot. Macro expansion occurs in early translation phases before actual compilation. That means that your requirement cannot be achieved in C++. But `std::map` (or `std::unordered_map`) is a associative container implementation that can be used to convert strings at run-time